# Nested object with square bracket notation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to achieve the following:

```
this.inputs[options.el.find('form').attr('class')] = {};

this.inputs[options.el.find('form').attr('class')][options.elements[x].selector] = false;
```

However, I'm unable to do the above without a syntax error!

Any ideas how I could achieve this Object structure?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the _syntax_, so I'm guessing your objects aren't structured how you think they are.

Comment: In order to answer you, I have two questions: what is the value for `options.elements[x].selector`? What is the Syntax error?

Comment: @AlexStack this: input[name="username"]

Comment: what is the message of the syntax error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That syntax looks legal, but these long one liners aren't doing anyone any favors. Break it apart a bit so you can find where it's failing.

```
var className = options.el.find('form').attr('class');
var selector = options.elements[x].selector;

this.inputs[className] = {};
this.inputs[className][selector] = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

The index to an object should always be a string:

```
var obj = {
  a: 2;
}

obj.a = 3; //a is 3 now
obj['a'] = 4;//a is 4 now
```

You said `options.elements[x].selector` is `input[name="username"]` so I guess in this line:

```
this.inputs[options.el.find('form').attr('class')][options.elements[x].selector] = false;
```

What you are really trying to do is:

```
this.inputs[options.el.find('form').attr('class')]['username'] = false;
```

So you can do like this:

```
var sel = options.elements[x].selector;
console.log( 'sel is ' + sel );
this.inputs[options.el.find('form').attr('class')][sel] = false;
```

Make sure that sel is a string. You may want to try

```
var sel = options.elements[x].selector.value;
```

The `.value` bit retrieves the text from inside an input element.